# Polite way of asking for something in a shop?

Tags: politeness

Is "ich nehme" a polite way of asking for something in a shop or somewhere like it? Would "ich möchte" be more of the thing to use in a store?

Comment: I often see people say "ich nehme" or "ich kriege". I have personally always found that a little impolite, but obviously many others don't. I would prefer "Ich hätte gern".

Comment: What is a more common thing to say, "ich nehme" "ich kriege" or "ich möchte"?

Comment: Betonung, Mimik, Gestik und Beziehung können hier einen Unterschied ums Ganze ausmachen. Mit "Ich möchte" oder "Ich hätte gern" kann man einen Angestellten auch herrisch anbrüllen.

Comment: Adding "bitte" makes almost every question polite.

Answer (score 3):

There are regional differences. For instance, a mere *ich nehme* would be rather impolite in Switzerland, where a more common way of asking for something would be *ich hätte gerne.*

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion "ich nehme", "ich kriege" and "ich möchte" are interchangeable and there is absolutely no difference regarding politeness or frequency of use. You can also add a "bitte" to each of those phrases, like "ich nehme bitte ...", which shows a extra bit of politeness.

Additionaly, as already pointed out in the comments, the biggest difference makes the way you pronounce it, your facial expressions and how you treat the other person in general. This means that shouting a sentence like "Ich möchte bitte eine Suppe" to the waiter is not polite, independent of the words you use.

Answer (score 0):

"ich nehme" and "ich möchte" are not polite ways of placing an order, but they are not particularly impolite either. They are less impolite than their literal translation to English, but if you value politeness I would recommend "Ich hätte gerne", "Ich bekomme bitte" or "ich nehme bitte".

But it also depends on the region you are in. In some areas "ich nehme" and "ich möchte" are very common and not the slightest bit impolite. The more important etiquacy is the more common the polite versions become

Answer (score -4):

Using **ich nehme …** shows the waiter you have already chosen:

> Was darf ich bringen? – Ich nehme den Fisch von der Tageskarte.

**Ich kriege** is the same but too casual for a restaurant. It's okay for ordering at a food truck:

> Was darf's sein? – Ich krieg' Bratwurst mit Pommes.

**Ich möchte etwas/hätte gerne …** indicates you want some suggestion or have some complicated wish:

> Was darf ich bringen? – Ich hätte den Salat gerne ohne Tomaten.
>
> Was darf ich bringen? – Ich möchte etwas herzhaftes.

Comment: "Ich kriege die Nürnberger, aber bitte mit Pommes statt Püree" kann man genauso sagen, oder "Ich nehme den Fisch, aber bitte ohne Gurken". Ebenso kann man "Ich hätte gern den Tafelspitz" sagen, ohne Sonderwünsche zu formulieren oder "Ich möchte ein Stück Sachertorte."

Comment: Wenn du die Kellner verwirren willst, tust du das.

Comment: @Janka Was ist dabei verwirrend?

Comment: So schlecht ist die Antwort nicht, dass sie gleich fünf Minusse verdient hätte. In der Tat finde ich Jankas Bedeutungsdifferenzierung nachvollziehbar, auch wenn sie in der Alltagspraxis wohl selten so genau umgesetzt wird.